# ClassNotFoundException: HelloStageDemo

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, scalafx

The code I'm running is from the homepage of http://www.scalafx.org. There are no compiler warnings but when it runs I get the exception. I first tried using jdk 1.7 with Scala 2.11 and ScalaFX 2.9.3-2.2.67 and got the equivalent error. I still get it with jdk 1.8 with Scala 2.11 and ScalaFX 2.11-8.0.20-R6. I'm hoping I'm stupidly missing something simple. This is all that gets written to the console:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-32.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\lib\scala-actors-2.11.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\lib\scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\lib\scala-library.jar;C:\Users\bhoeppner\Downloads\ScalaFX 8\scalafx_2.11-8.0.20-R6.jar;C:\Users\bhoeppner\Downloads\ScalaFX 8\scalafx_2.11-8.0.20-R6-javadoc.jar;C:\Users\bhoeppner\Downloads\ScalaFX 8\scalafx_2.11-8.0.20-R6-sources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain HelloStageDemo

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloStageDemo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you trying to run HelloStageDemo from a directory on your classpath? Double check.

Comment: HelloStageDemo.class must be found (at the "root" level) in one of the directories in your classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarsAtomic and Hot Licks were correct. This is how I got it to work:

Dragged the file containing HelloStageDemo to the src folder, which was already marked as Sources Root.

- Right-clicked on the project node and selected "Open Module Settings."
- Clicked the "Dependencies" tab.
- Clicked the green plus sign and pressed Enter for "Jars or directories..."
- Browsed to my projects src folder and Clicked the OK button.
- Compiling yielded some scala-reflect errors.
- Added my scala\lib folder to module dependencies in the same way as I had my src folder.
- Compiled and it ran.

Thanks for steering me straight!

Comment: I think figuring out how to run java program from command line would be of benefit. You can start with 'Hello, world' consisting of a single class file, then go to program of a few classes (no external jars), and then to program which has dependencies in 3rd party jars.